# How many reduced fractions a/b such that ab=20! and 0 < a/b < 1?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, fractions

(a, b have to be integers)

Assuming a,b both positive, we get
$ab<b^{2}$

Therefore, $b> \sqrt{20!}$

Similarly, $a < \sqrt{20!}$

I am stuck after this. Help?

Comment: Let $A$ be the set of all divisors $a$ of $20!$ such that $a<\sqrt{20!}$. Define $B$ in a similar way. Now $D=A\cup B$ where $D$ is the set of all divisors

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $a<b$ and they have no common prime factors. Now make a list of all the prime factors of $20!$....

Comment: got till that, but how do I proceed?

Comment: @redx try counting?

Comment: do I have to use the highest powers of the prime factors?

Comment: @redx I don’t know what that question means.

Comment: okay, i counted. 8 prime factors.. but how do I approach the problem after that? I get that b has to have 11,13,17,19 as because they appear only once in 20! and a< (20!)^1/2... but how do I divide the rest of the prime factors among a and b keeping 0<a/b<1?

Comment: Choose a subset of the primes to be potential factors of $a$.  How many ways to do that?  The rest would be factors of $b$.  Half the partitions will work because $a \lt b$.  We don't need to compute any of the $a$s or $b$s as we were just asked how many there are.

Comment: done. thank you :)